# Автоувеличение файла по Кбайт

Tags: sql, sql-server

При создании БД можно задать автоувеличение файла (обычно в Мб). Как явно указать в Кб?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'data1', FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
```

или 1024MB, или 1024GB